# "resulted in" vs "resulted on"

Tags: prepositions

Consider the sentence

> The attack resulted in Robert breaking his ankle.

Is *resulted in* correct here? What about *resulted on*, would it be correct here or in any other sentence? what other word can be used here (in, to, ...)?

According to Google search results, *resulted in* is much more frequently used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can use a [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=result%20in%2C%20result%20to%2C%20result%20into%2C%20result%20on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cresult%20in%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresult%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresult%20into%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cresult%20on%3B%2Cc0). It is obvious from this diagram, that the proper preposition is *in*. See also this [question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/133714/resulting-in-vs-resulting-on) (*English Language Learners*). So

> The attack resulted in Robert breaking his ankle.

Also, in simple cases like this you could also use an [online grammar editor](http://www.reverso.net/spell-checker/english-spelling-grammar/) like that of Reverso. See attached picture below:

[image]

I don't know what is your mother tongue ; you could use an online translator service like Deepl. E.g. [for a French native speaker one gets](https://www.deepl.com/translator#fr/en/L'attaque%20a%20eu%20pour%20cons%C3%A9quence%20que%20Robert%20s'est%20cass%C3%A9%20la%20cheville.):

> L'attaque a eu pour conséquence que Robert s'est cassé la cheville.
>
> The attack resulted in Robert breaking his ankle.

Here is an interesting [thread](https://www.manilatimes.net/three-years-apart-two-sos-resulting-resulting/292528/) (*two SOS about ‘resulting to’ and ‘resulting in’*).

Comment: ah interesting, wasnt aware of that tool, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Resulted on would reference a point in time or on a thing. Such as:

> Bogeys resulted on each occasion.
>
> There are a few posts from the firefight that has resulted on Facebook.

A consensus definition appeared to emerge that the Japanese gold standard of grime was what resulted on one white shirt worn by a salary man for one day.

Comment: Your second sentence is ungrammatical. I was about to say that the subject is *posts*, so the verb should be *have*, but even that doesn't result in the sentence making sense. To use the construction you did, it would need to be ***have appeared*** *on Facebook*. The verb *resulted* just doesn't work in that construction. And if you change it, it would become *resulted* ***in***, so it's not a good example sentence to make your point.

Comment: In the second example, "resulted on" is not a phrase. The grouping is *There are (a few posts from the (firefight that has resulted) on Facebook)*.

Comment: It could be rewritten as *There are a few posts on Facebook from the firefight that resulted.*